# Insert into Table from another table and an independent value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, subquery

Say I have two tables,

```
Employee
name address phone phone_type

EmployeeContacts
name address phone
```

Hence, can I do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Employee name, address, phone VALUES(SELECT name, address, phone from EmployeeContacts where name = "Joe") and phoneType = "mobile"
```

?

Basically, insert certain values selected from one table and INSERT an extra value as well?

If not, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `insert . . . select` form:

```
INSERT INTO Employee(name, address, phone, phonetype)
    SELECT name, address, phone, 'mobile'
    from EmployeeContacts
    where name = 'Joe'
```

Comment: Will that insert phoneType = "mobile" or check it as a condition?

Comment: @gran_profaci . . . This inserts it as the phone type.  I don't know what it would mean to "check it as a condition".

Comment: That seems way better. Thanks.. lemme test it!